# WooCommerce - Trying to give a partner discount at the end of my pdf

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For my webshop I want to add a partner discount at the end of my pdf file.
Now I am trying to add the partner discount through a category.
The problem right now is that the pdf only picks the last category, so will always give 50% discount. 
When I log the category I get "Versie Upgrade". But that isn't the category attached by the order. How can I add the category to the right order?

```
    if ($category == 'Licenties' ) {
        $korting = 0.10;
    } else if ($category == 'Onderhoud en Support') {
        $korting = 0.20;
    } else if ($category == 'Onderhouds Upgrade') {
        $korting = 0.30;
    } else if ($category == 'Pakket Switch') {
        $korting = 0.40;
    } else if ($category == 'Versie Upgrade') {
        $korting = 0.50;
    } else {
        $korting = 0;
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/rg9LUy6q

http://prntscr.com/iof6a4

Comment: Product categories are not assigned to an order, but to each order item in it. So as the provided hook doesn't allow to "Loop" through Order items, you will not be able to get any product categories involved in that order items… Also an Order can have many items so different product categories.

Comment: So what would be you're advice to me if I may ask?

Comment: As the plugin you are using is a relative closed commercial plugin from RightPress (CodeCanyon), you should better ask in author support threads, as we don't have any access to it. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Oke no problem, atleast thanks for the help :)